# Openlayer Linestring with two or more lines on the one or more coordinates?

Tags: coordinates, openlayers

My problem is the following:
Linestring with two or more lines on the one or more coordinates.

With several LineStrings only one string is shown in the map, I know, the LineStrings also use the same coordinates.
Is there a way that the LineStrings can use one and the same coordinates, but a shift of the line (to have for example three lines next to each other) takes place in the structure of the map?

The code is a bit better, which explains a lot:

```
  var logoElement = document.createElement ('a');
      logoElement.href = 'http://www.schienenpost.de/';
      logoElement.target = '_blank';

  var logoImage = document.createElement ('img');
      logoImage.src = 'http://www.schienenpost.de/schienenpost.png';
      logoElement.appendChild (logoImage);

  var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style ({
     image: new ol.style.Icon (/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
        anchor: [0.5, 1.0],
        src: 'http://www.schienenpost.de/marker/marker.png'
     }))
  });

  var scaleLineControl = new ol.control.ScaleLine();

  var markerStartEnd = function (layer,feature) {
     var i, iconFeature, iconFeatures = [], coordinates, nameLine; 
     coordinates = feature.getGeometry ().getCoordinates (); 
     nameLine = feature.getProperties () ['name']; 
     i = 0;
     iconFeature = new ol.Feature ({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point (coordinates[i]),
        name: 'Start'+nameLine,
     });
     iconFeature.setStyle (iconStyle);
     iconFeatures.push (iconFeature);
     i = coordinates.length - 1; 
     iconFeature = new ol.Feature ({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point (coordinates[i]),
        name: 'End'+nameLine,
     });
     iconFeature.setStyle (iconStyle);
     iconFeatures.push (iconFeature);
     layer.getSource ().addFeatures (iconFeatures);
  };

  var layerLines = new ol.layer.Vector ({
     source: new ol.source.Vector ({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON (),
        url: 'schienenpost.geojson',
        useSpatialIndex: false
     }),
     style: new ol.style.Style ({stroke: new ol.style.Stroke ({color : 'red', width: 3})}),
  });

  var layerMarker = new ol.layer.Vector ({
     title: 'Marker',
     source: new ol.source.Vector ()
  });

  var element = document.getElementById ('popup');

  var popup = new ol.Overlay ({
     element: element,
     positioning: 'bottom-center',
     stopEvent: false,
     offset: [0, -0]
  });

  var map = new ol.Map ({
     controls: ol.control.defaults ()
     .extend ([
        new ol.control.OverviewMap (),
        new ol.control.FullScreen (),
        scaleLineControl
     ]),
     //target 'map',
     target: document.getElementById ('map'),
     layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile ({
           source: new ol.source.OSM ()
        }),
     ],
     view: new ol.View ({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat ([10.627, 53.620]),
        zoom: 8
     }),
     logo: logoElement
  });

  map.addOverlay (popup);
  map.addLayer (layerLines);
  map.addLayer (layerMarker);


  map.once ('moveend', function(e) {
     layerLines.getSource ().getFeaturesCollection ().forEach (function (feature) {
        markerStartEnd (layerMarker,feature);
     });
  });

  map.on ('click', function (evt) {
     var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel (evt.pixel,
     function (feature) {
        return feature;
     });
     if (feature) {
        var coordinates = feature.getGeometry ().getCoordinates ();
        var clickpoint  = map.getCoordinateFromPixel (evt.pixel);
        if (!isNaN (coordinates [0])) { // Punkt
           popup.setPosition (coordinates);
        } else if (!isNaN (coordinates [0][0])) { // Linie
           popup.setPosition (clickpoint);
        } else { // kein brauchbares feature
           $ (element).popover ('destroy');
           return;
        }
        $ (element).popover ({
           'placement': 'top',
           'html': true,
           'content': feature.get ('name')
        });
        $ (element).popover ().data ('bs.popover').options.content = feature.get ('name');
        $ (element).popover ('show');
        } else {
           $ (element).popover ('hide');
        }
  });

  map.on ('pointermove', function(e) {
     if (e.dragging) {
        $ (element).popover ('destroy');
        return;
     }
     var pixel = map.getEventPixel (e.originalEvent);
     var hit = map.hasFeatureAtPixel (pixel);
     map.getTarget ().style.cursor = hit ? 'pointer' : '';
  });
```

Comment: Why did you make your code italics?

Comment: Then probably the "i" was for "Italic", I did not know.